# Recommended ufw port configuration to secure tomcat web-application ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, port, security, ufw

Assuming an ubuntu server operating web applications on Tomcat (with redirection from apache 80 to 8080).

What is the recommended port configuration to secure the server? Thanks.

P.S.: I would like to keep it simple and use ufw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a firewall, you close all the connection coming from outside. So just open the port 80 seems to be sufficient. You will maybe need to an external access like SSH to monitor your server.